# Consider $x = A[v]_+ + B[-v]_+$, under what conditions on A & B is there a solution v for every x

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

Consider the vector equality

$$x = A[v]_+ + B[-v]_+$$

where $[v]_+$ is the elementwise rectifier function, i.e.

$$[x]_+ = \begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } x > 0, \\ 
0 & \mbox{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$

**Question:** Under what conditions on A and B does there always exist a solution $v$ for every $x$, i. e. when does

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^N \,\,\exists v\in\mathbb{R}^M\quad x = A[v]_+ + B[-v]_+$$

hold?

For simplicity consider $N = M$ and $A, B$ full rank. In the case $N = M = 1$ we simply need $A*B < 0$. The case $N = M = 2$ is considerably harder: A trivial solution is $B = -A$, but from numerical tests I see that there exist many non-trivial solutions (I set A = Id, and draw B randomly from an iid Gaussian distribution, then about every third draw returns a valid B). I tested some intuitions (like eigenvalues of $AB^\top$) but none of them proofed sufficient (or even necessary) for a solution. Unfortunately, one cannot simply compute the optimal $v$ analytically (in terms of MSE), and then test for equality, so I am a bit stuck on how to handle that problem. Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since $A [v]_+ + B [-v]_+ = \sum_i a_i [v_i]_+ + \sum_i b_i [-v_i]_+$, where $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are columns of $A$ and $B$, and there is at most $M$ non-zero terms in the sum, it seems that a necessary requirement is that any $M$ columns of $A$ or $B$ span the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks, Budenn! But it looks to me that this reasoning leaves aside the nonnegativity of the factors. In some sense, a sufficient condition would be that there are at least $M$ columns in $A$ and $B$ such that $x = Q[v]_+$, where $Q$ are the $M$ columns. But that condition might not be necessary, since every solution of $x$ can employ a different set of columns (which relaxes the problem).